# Construct values in derived column based combination of values from another columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following values.

```
gl_accountcode  gl_reference    gl_subledger_code   MOE
40000000003000  00001064        TOTDOO01    
40000000003102  00001064        TOTDOO01            60
40002073999807  00001064        TOTDOO01    
40000000003000  00025928        WATSEC01    
40000000003102  00025928        WATSEC01            60
40305558609795  00025928        WATSEC01            60
```

I want to populate MOE column with 60 when substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' as condition 1 and also when  (B.gl_accountcode) = '40000000003102' and  substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' for same GL Reference as condition 2.

I picked up two GL references "00001064" and '00025928' for this example.

I don't want to populate '60' in MOE column when substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) is not '60' and (B.gl_accountcode) = '40000000003102' for same GL Reference which seems to happening with below sql.

```
select 
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_accountcode)) as 'GL AccountCode',
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_reference)) as 'GL Reference',
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_subledger_code)) as 'GL Subledger Code',
CASE 
WHEN substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' OR (LTRIM(RTRIM(B.gl_accountcode))) =       '40000000003102' THEN '60'
ELSE ''
END MOE 
from dbo.pronto_NZD_GLTransUnion B
where B.gl_reference in ( '00025928', '00001064')
order by B.gl_reference, B.gl_accountcode
```

I think I need to self join the table but I can't get my head around it. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... 60 when substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' as condition 1 and also when (B.gl_accountcode) = '40000000003102' and substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' for same GL Reference as condition 2.
>
> I don't want to populate '60' in MOE column when substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) is not '60' and (B.gl_accountcode) = '40000000003102'

Easier said is...

```
60 when 

substring(x) = '60'
OR
(B.gl_accountcode = 'y' and substring(x) = '60')

(...and not when (B.gl_accountcode = 'y' and substring(x) <> '60')
```

Which basically is

```
substring(x) = '60'
```

So your final statement is:

```
select 
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_accountcode)) as 'GL AccountCode',
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_reference)) as 'GL Reference',
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_subledger_code)) as 'GL Subledger Code',
CASE 
WHEN substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' 
THEN '60'
ELSE ''
END MOE 
from pronto_NZD_GLTransUnion B
where B.gl_reference in ( '00025928', '00001064')
order by B.gl_reference, B.gl_accountcode
```

EDIT: While I'm waiting for your desired result, could this be what you're looking for?

```
select 
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_accountcode)) as 'GL AccountCode',
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_reference)) as 'GL Reference',
RTRIM(LTRIM(B.gl_subledger_code)) as 'GL Subledger Code',
CASE 
WHEN substring(B.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' THEN '60'
WHEN gl_accountcode = '40000000003102' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pronto_NZD_GLTransUnion a WHERE substring(a.gl_accountcode,9,2) = '60' AND a.gl_reference = B.gl_reference) THEN '60'
ELSE ''
END MOE 
from pronto_NZD_GLTransUnion B
where B.gl_reference in ( '00025928', '00001064')
order by B.gl_reference, B.gl_accountcode
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27268/3/0)

Comment: I want to populate MOE as '60' When substring (B.gl_accountcode) = '60'  and  B.gl_accountcode = '40000000003102' for same gl_reference . Please note they are same fields but they appear in different rows. This condition is true when gl_reference is '00025928' and not when gl_reference is '00001064'. My code wrongly populates  MOE as '60' B.gl_accountcode = '40000000003102' and ubstring (B.gl_accountcode) <> '60' ( for gl_reference is '00001064'). I need a code which also looks at gl_reference column and doesn't populate MOE as '60' when both conditions don't meet. Hope it make sense.

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion in wording my question. I want a code which always populate MOE as '60' when substring(gl_accountcode) = '60' and gl_accountcode = '40000000003102' for same gl_reference. Please note this is true for row 5 and row 6 in below output. I don't want to populate MOE as '60' when gl_accountcode = '40000000003102' but substring(gl_accountcode) <> '60' for the same gl_reference as in case with row 2.

So it very much depends on substring(gl_accountcode) = '60' for same for the gl_reference

Hope it give better understanding of the result I need.

Comment: Okay, I begin to understand. But can you post the desired result based on your sample data? Should all rows for the same gl_reference have 60 then?

Comment: @prashant Updated my answer, and please see the comment above, if it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: You are a star mate. I didn't know you could also do a self join before FROM clause like you did. Thanks heaps. I think I got the results I wanted. Its my first question on Stack Overflow. Is there a way, I can mark your answer correct !

Comment: @prashant You're welcome :) To accept you can click on the check left to my answer. Thanks. You can also have a quick read about how stackoverflow works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/about).